# Nginx process and php-fpm share volumes

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have problems with a share volumes that both nginx apline and php-fpm can write and delete folder and file.
Nginx container will create static file on var/run.

```
FROM nginx:alpine
RUN set -x ; \
addgroup -g 82 -S www-data ; \
adduser -u 82 -D -S -G www-data www-data && exit 0 ; exit 1

RUN chmod 777 -R /var/run

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/static-cache/
```

I also create a same directory on php-fpm container so it can clear all the cache when I update a page.

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

RUN apk add shadow && usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data

RUN chmod 777 -R /var/run

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/static-cache.

WORKDIR /var/www/html/
```

A mount volume will link these two directories between 2 containers.
However, when I save a page, I'm not able to clear any folder on php-fpm container due to permision denied.
Is ther any solutions to solve arround this?

Comment: An important information is missing in your question: How do you start the containers? Please provide the commands (or the `docker-compose.yml` file if you use `docker-compose`)

Comment: just simply: docker-compose up.

Comment: I just checked and nginx create file with read permission only:
    drwx------    3 nginx    www-data. 
I think that is why my web can not delete any file.
Is there a way that nginx process create files that are able to delete
Reference link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-fastcgi-caching-with-nginx-on-your-vps